# Mongod: Command Not Found (OS X)

Tags: macos, mongodb

I am trying to test MongoDB and I have it all downloaded and moved into the root folder. I can navigate to the folder that holds the mongod, but when I try to run it by typing "mongod" into my terminal, I get a message that says:

> "mongod: command not found"

Answer (score 31):

Both answers above are correct. 
You can either specify the path in one of the following files: .profile, .bashrc, or .bash_profile

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin"
```

then call the daemon or the shell directly

```
mongod
mongo
```

Or for the commands not in the $PATH, use ./mongo or ./mongod from the directory containing these files. This solution can be verbose has you will have to eventually append the whole path when calling these commands from another directory.

```
/usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongod
or
/usr/local/mongodb/bin$ ./mongod
```

Comment: NOTE: if you update your Mac to Sierra you will need to re-export your paths as shown above.

Comment: In the latest hombrew version (Homebrew 3.3.12) running in monterey, mongo is installed in `/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community@x.x/` rather than `/usr/local/mongodb`.

Comment: What helped me resolve the issue was running: `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community@5.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` and then run `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 14):

"Mongod" isn't a stand-alone command. You need to run the command like this:

```
./mongodb/bin/mongod
```

I used this [webpage](https://blog.bigspaceship.com/installing-mongodb-on-mac-5274c77a8ee9) to help me answer this question.

Comment: the link you mentioned no longer exists.

Answer (score 14):

I received the same error message because I used the wrong command to run `mongod` (meant for M1s) for my 2019 MacBook with an Intel processor. You can skip past Homebrew updates and MongoDB installation but here's how I resolved my issue:

Download Xcode Command Line tools.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Allow Homebrew to add and access MongoDB:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Update Homebrew:

```
brew update
```

Install MongoDB Community Edition (@6.0 is the latest version at the time of this post):

```
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

macOS with Intel processors:

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork
```

macOS with Apple M1 processors:

```
mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork
```

Then open the shell:

```
mongosh
```

Or just run `mongod`.

[Official documentation on installation here.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
MongoDB 6.0 Community Edition supports macOS 10.14 or later.

Comment: I have been searching a solution for a while. Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

1. brew tap mongodb/brew
2. brew install mongodb-community@4.2
3. mongod

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 12):

For example, install 64bit MongoDB 2.6.12 on macOS Catalina.
(for newest versions you may go to https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community for your platform).

1. Download, extract and move:

   `wget http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz`

   `tar xzf mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.12.tgz`

   `mv mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.12/ /usr/local/mongodb/`
2. Add to file `~/.zshrc` this:

   `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin"`

   PS: `.bash_profile` or `.profile` not worked in my case
3. Reload terminal (or close, open it):

   `source ~/.zshrc`
4. Make directory for data and set rights:

   `mkdir -p ~/data/db`

   `chown -R mongodb.mongodb ~/data/db`
5. Run MongoDB:

   `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the name of the folder that contains the command `mongod` into your PATH so your shell knows where to find it.

So, if `mongod` is in /usr/bin/freddyfrog, you would edit `~/.profile` and find the line that says `PATH=` and edit it to look like this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/bin/freddyfrog
```

Then login again to make it take effect.

Answer (score 5):

3 steps:

Step 1:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mongodb/bin"
```

OR

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.2/bin"
```

(replace version number with your local version)

The first step will allow you to run the command, but will get you another error: "/data/db does not exit" so you have to

Step 2 :

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

Now /data/db is read only, but it has to be writable also so

Step 3 :

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME /data/db
```

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to install a previous version (3.6) using latest documentation (4.2 is already released). So, they now call it `mongodb-community@3.6`.

In order to update PATH for such setup, the statement should be

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@3.6/bin";
```

I got hint from @retroGiant 's answer

Comment: My Indian bhrata, this worked. Thanks. 

Others - make sure you get the path right on Mac OS X Catalina. Other comments are linking to wrong path.

Answer (score 3):

run this command, it works:

`brew services start mongodb-community@4.0`

Answer (score 3):

I have installed `mongodb-community@3.2`, was facing the same issue. I followed below steps.

1. open bash profile in any editor (you can also try - `vi ~/.bash_profile`)
2. write this `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@3.2/bin"` & save.
3. do this . `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 2):

In root directory

```
sudo mkdir data
cd data 
mkdir db
```

then

```
sudo chown -R yourUsername /data/
```

copy path of your mongodb/bin  [downloaded folder](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community) (I suggest you put it in home folder not root dir)

[image]

in terminal

export PATH="paste the link here :$PATH"

now it should work but if not

In case you are using different Unix shell and
trying to execute mongod within visual studio code( for example ),
make sure to read the documentation to link PATH.

For example, if you are using [zsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshall) create .zprofile in your home directory.

`touch .zprofile`

copy your previously made PATH into .zprofile

[image]

[image]

Now everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same and later I have found that now it's very straight forward to install the new MongoDB Community Edition like below:

#### Installing MongoDB 6.0 Community Edition

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

Note: If you haven't yet install `brew` then follow this link: https://brew.sh/#install

#### Update Homebrew

```
brew update
```

#### Install MongoDB

```
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

#### The installation includes the following binaries:

- The `mongod` server
- The `mongos` sharded cluster query router
- The MongoDB Shell, `mongosh`

### Run MongoDB Community Edition

#### To run MongoDB (i.e. the mongod process) as a macOS service, run:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@6.0
```

#### To stop a `mongod` running as a macOS service, use the following command as needed:

```
brew services stop mongodb-community@6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**MongoDB 5.0 issue resolved - SEP/2022**

do following steps

step 1: open a .zshrc file if it does not exist it will create by itself by following the command. For opening or creating a .zshrc file below command is the same.

```
vim .zshrc
```

step 2: insert value in it by pressing **'i'**

step 3: insert the below command there or paste it there.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@5.0/bin"
```

step 4: to exit click on **esc** key and the write **:wq**

step 5: Close the terminal and reopen it and type the below command

```
mongo
```

**Output**

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.11
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:279021/?
compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
```

Successfully integrated mongo

happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

If you use brew then check the path:
`brew list`
`brew list mongodb-community@...`
then add it to `.zshrc`

[zsh: command not found: mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68695241/)

after that use `mongosh` instead of `mongo`

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is a little bit unrelated, but if you using vscode & would like to interact with mongoDB using command line, have a read.**

I was looking to use mongod command as well (as i love to use command to interact with mongoDB), but after several attempts of install i completely give up. Until i found this, the [mongoDB vscode extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/mongodb).

The extension is loading the data pretty fast just like mongod command compare to mongo compass. It allow you to perform CRUD & aggregation in the mongoDB playground, and most importantly you able to retrieve the command on next execution by storing your command in a file with .mongodb extension.

*Update: After using it several weeks, everything is nice, just need to make sure you connecting to the right mongoDB connection (if you establish few different connection)

Answer (score -1):

### **Fix for MongoDB version 6.0 and above**

If you’re using **mongodb version 6.0, and above**, the command you’d need to use for entering the **mongodb shell is changed from mongo to mongosh:**

```
$ mongosh
```

And that’s it✅! Yeah! It’s really that simple (as long as this is actually the problem in your specific scenario).

Answer (score -1):

for me i Used the latest version of mongoDb (**mongodb-community@6.0**) and for that we should use **mongosh** instead of **mongod**
[image]