# command not found: mongo, after it's installed (OS X)

Tags: mongodb, macos, installation

After following official instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) to install mongo-community, it cannot find the command to start mongo.

Steps I used to install mongo:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@3.6
```

The installation was successful, but when I tried to start mongo with `mongo`. This error appears: 
`zsh: command not found: mongo`

Tried the solutions at [Mongod: Command Not Found (OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862808/mongod-command-not-found-os-x), none of them worked.
Also, can't seem to find where mongo is located.

Thank in advance!

Comment: That means either the installation didn't complete successfully or `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `$PATH` variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh for adding the path to zsh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the path to "mongo" to your terminal shell:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community@3.6/3.6.14/bin"
```

(replace version number with your local version)

It cannot find the command since `$PATH` is not set correctly. After MongoDB moved [from open source to community liscence](https://www.mongodb.com/licensing/server-side-public-license) on Oct 16, 2018, the installation path on Mac changed. It's installed in `/usr/local/Cellar` (reference: [Location of the mongodb database on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827915/location-of-the-mongodb-database-on-mac)).

Thanks to @kevinadi for point out the issue.

Comment: Just for information, this works with 3.4 version too.

This is the path for 3.4 version: `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community@3.4/3.4.23/bin`

Comment: For me this here worked fine: 
export `PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/4.2.2/bin"`

Answer (score 2):

[mongodb shell reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongo-shell/)

In my case I couldn't find mongo command as 2022, so I used `mongosh`
and it worked fine.