# How to find location of "mongod" command?

Tags: linux, mongodb, macos, shell, command-line

I would like to run MondoDB locally. I am unable to do so because upon running

```
mongod -config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

I get the error:

```
-bash: mongod: command not found
```

I saw in the answer to this question: [Mongod: Command Not Found (OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862808/mongod-command-not-found-os-x)  that I need to add the name of the folder that contains the command to PATH.

I saw in the answer to this question: [Shell - How to find directory of some command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869100/shell-how-to-find-directory-of-some-command) that I can run "type -a mongod", "which mongod", among other solutions to find its location, but I do not get any output in my terminal upon running those commands.

Could you please let me know how I could find the location on the "mongod" command so that I can run it locally? Thank you.

Comment: Is mongo installed on your system?

Comment: So I'm not quite sure what happened, but I just followed https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ and the issue resolved itself. I am not sure if mongo was properly installed otherwise.

Comment: I think one thing I did differently was run the installation commands in my root directory instead of a project directory, but I am not sure if that would make a difference.